# How to cause a click event?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

The form has a button on it that when clicked provides a dropdown of some various types.  How can I cause a click event on any of these types when the form is ready?

This is what I tried, but doesn't work.

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("advanced-search-add-text-row").click();
    });
</script>

  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle advanced-search-add-row-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphicon-white"></span>
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
      <li><%= link_to I18n.t("advanced_search.type.text"), "javascript:void(0)", :class => "advanced-search-add-row advanced-search-add-text-row", "data-type" => "text" %></li>
      <li><%= link_to I18n.t("advanced_search.type.date"), "javascript:void(0)", :class => "advanced-search-add-row advanced-search-add-date-row", "data-type" => "date" %></li>
      <li><%= link_to I18n.t("advanced_search.type.boolean"), "javascript:void(0)", :class => "advanced-search-add-row advanced-search-add-bool-row", "data-type" => "boolean" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to I18n.t("advanced_search.type.controlled_value"), "javascript:void(0)", :class => "advanced-search-add-row advanced-search-add-enum-row", "data-type" => "enum" %></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

The javascript for creating the row:

```
  $advancedSearchContainer.on("click", ".advanced-search-add-row", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    var index = $("input[id^='v']", $advancedSearchRowContainer).length;

    var adding_as_first_row = false;
    if (index == 0) {
      adding_as_first_row = true;
    }

    while ($(":input[name='f"+index+"']", $advancedSearchContainer).length > 0) {
      index += 1;
    }

    addAdvancedSearchRow(index, $(this).data("type"), adding_as_first_row, {});

    // hide the drop down menu after clicking an option
    $(this).closest(".dropdown-menu").siblings(".advanced-search-add-row-dropdown").trigger("click");
  });
```

Comment: are you trying to actually dispatch the click event? If so use `trigger('click')`. not `click()`.  `click()` is just a shortcut for `.on('click',...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

So change the line:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("advanced-search-add-text-row").click();
```

to:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("advanced-search-add-text-row")[0].click();
```

Instead, using jQuery you can write:

```
$(".advanced-search-add-text-row").trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementsbyClassName returns an array! And you cannot execute the click function on the whole array, you need to click on each element:

```
elems=document.getElementsByClassName("class");
for(i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
elems[i].click();
}
```